# i want know how applicat css in my login.html

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

hello my friend i install bootstrap in my poject adn he works fine just i want to know how i can apllicate this bootstrap
style  https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dldxB with css  and adapt it to my login.html thank you

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class ="row text-center">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md3">
   <form action="" method="Post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Nom d'Utilisateur</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"  
placeholder="Tapez le Nom d'Utilisateur">

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Mot de Passe</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" 
placeholder="Mot de Passe">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrer</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your bootstrap CSS file in your **base.html** template, in **head** section:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: i add it because i applicate css in home.html but i account application with login i don't know how i do it ??